# Preciso inicializar a variável com o valor 0, por quê?

Tags: java, variáveis, switch, declaração-de-variável, double

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int codigo, quantidade;
        double preco;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        codigo = sc.nextInt();
        quantidade = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        switch (codigo) {
        case 1:
            preco = 4.0 * quantidade;
            break;
        case 2:
            preco = 4.5 * quantidade;
            break;
        case 3:
            preco = 5.0 * quantidade;
            break;
        case 4:
            preco = 2.0 * quantidade;
            break;
        case 5:
            preco = 1.5 * quantidade;
            break;
        }


System.out.printf("Total: R$ %.2f%n", preco);
    }

}
```

No treco de código `System.out.printf("Total: R$ %.2f%n", preco);` indica um erro que no trecho de inicialização da variável preco `double preco;` preciso inicializar ela com o valor 0 `double preco = 0` mas por que não posso inicializar ela sem o valor 0? Indica esse erro: 
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The local variable preco may not have been initialized

```
at Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não precisa inicializar `preco` com 0, mas você precisa garantir que essa variável será inicializada antes de você printa-la na tela.

Veja que no seu código você inicializa `preco` dentro de um `switch`, mas isso só ocorre se o valor de `codigo` for igual a 1, 2, 3, 4 ou 5.

E se o valor de `codigo` for 6? `preco` não será inicializado, e portanto o compilador te retorna um erro.

Você pode adicionar uma cláusula `default` para garantir que `codigo` sempre será inicializado, dessa forma o compilador irá aceitar o seu código.

```
switch (codigo) {
case 1:
    preco = 4.0 * quantidade;
    break;
case 2:
    preco = 4.5 * quantidade;
    break;
case 3:
    preco = 5.0 * quantidade;
    break;
case 4:
    preco = 2.0 * quantidade;
    break;
case 5:
    preco = 1.5 * quantidade;
    break;
default:
    preco = 0;
}
```

Você também pode tratar isso de outra forma, como retornar uma mensagem de código inválido para o usuário, apenas garanta que `preco` seja inicializado de alguma forma.